# Einstein Vision : Train a Dataset : Failed to get dataset download url

Tags: api, einstein, data-set, training

I have created two datasets via REST API calls, one with a dropboxlink to the .zip file and one from the .zip file on my local drive.
Both datasets are available and the statusMsg is SUCCEEDED.

When I try to train the datasets, for both I get the error message: "Failed to get dataset download url"

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in my dataset.zip.
I changed the following things, without trying out what the significant change was:

- changed labels (foldernames) from numbers to letters, starting with a capital letter
- removed "_" from the image filename
- smaller dataset